# How to recover a rotor in higher dimensions from the vectors?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I'd like to recover a rotor in geometric algebra where I know which (multi)vectors transform to given rotated (multi)vectors. I've found many references for 3D/4D dimensions (something like $\sum e_if_i$), but I need a formula for any dimension. Is there an easy one?

Also more importantly, how do I prove that it works?

Because I actually need to rotate multivectors $A_i=ae_i+cf_i$ (or maybe grade-3 basis) to new ones of this form, so that I will need to derive/check that the formula also works for a multivector basis.

Comment: Are you asking about how to solve the versor equation $X A_i X^{-1} = B_i$ where $X$ is unknown rotor, $A_i$ and $B_i$ are $n$ known multivectors? I think you can solve this equation in a least squares sense by finding the eigenvector corresponding to least eigenvalue of a quadratic form. That works for any dimension. If you don't know how to translate GA multivector expressions to LA matrices check Perwass book: Geometric Algebra With Applications in Engineering

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon This is correct. Thanks. I've posted what I've found so far as an answer. In my particular case I realized in only need low dimensional results, and I guessed the solution for my multivectors.

Answer (score 0):

For other readers, I'd like to post what I've found out so far:

Apparently, there is an implementation in the Python [clifford](https://clifford.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/clifford.tools.orthoFrames2Versor.html#clifford.tools.orthoFrames2Versor) package of a cartan-daydonny algorithm, which makes me assume there is no closed form solution for higher dimensions.

In the researchgate.net [discussion](https://www.researchgate.net/post/4D_rotations_and_rotors_can_a_general_expression_be_derived) I've found a [derivation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Francisco-Montoya-7/post/4D_rotations_and_rotors_can_a_general_expression_be_derived/attachment/5fd6015ee35e2b0001fe0b14/AS%3A968251580354560%401607860574094/download/nD_Rotor_explanation.pdf) but there may be an error in the assumptions about rotors making the derivation invalid in higher dimensions. There is another linked [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254915539_Determining_a_versor_in_nD_geometric_algebra_from_the_known_transformation_of_n_vectors), but it's beyond what I can understand.